# approximation of $e^{-\beta x}$ with e^{-L x^2}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponential-function

I want to approximate $$e^{- \beta x} $$ with Gaussian function $$e^{-L x^2}$$.
How can I do that? what will be relation between $\beta$ and $L$ ?

Comment: The question is unclear. Where do you wish to have an approximation? What is an approximation, in your context?

Comment: For $x=0:\infty $, I want to use $f_2(x)=e^{−L x^2}$ instead of $f_1(x) = e^{-\beta x}$. For example criteria can be $|f_2(x)−f_1(x)|<10^{−6}$.